# Hessian: Is this a right way of saying?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

I have a question about the usage of the term *Hessian* in multivariate functions: Here is the problem and solution:

Given $f(x,y)= x^3+2xy-5x-y^2$, $f'_x=3x^2+2y-5$ & $f'_y=2x-2y$. Solving for stationary points, $(x,y) = (1,1) \text{ or } (-\frac 53, -\frac 53) $.

$f''_{xx} = 6x$, $f''_{yy}=-2$ & $f''_{xy} = 2$

Here is when my question comes in. Consider $(x,y) = (1,1)$.

Can I say that the *Hessian* is $f''_{xx}f''_{yy} - (f''_{xy})^2 = 6(1)(-2)-4= -16?$
After all, it is actually the determinant of the Hessian matrix. I am thinking that since the Jacobian is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix, the same thing applies here.

(Of course, following this we know $(1,1)$ is a saddle point of $f$.) Since this is not the main point of this question, I shall halt my working here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a bit confusing. But [Hessian is a matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hessian.html).
It is not very good to call [the determinant of the Jacobian matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html) just "Jacobian", because it is indeed a matrix, too.

Comment: thank you for the link, that's sufficient for me right now.